# Twig date and time formatting with text in between

Tags: php, twig

In Twig I want to show a DateTime variable like this:

`2018-10-22 at 15:03:18`

I tried this: `{{ dateTimeVariable |date('Y-m-d at H:i:s') }}`, but this returns

`2018-10-22 pm31 15:03:18`

The result makes sense because the `a` from `at` returns the lowercase `am` or `pm` and `t` the numbers in the month. For more on this, see the [date formatting guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

How though, can I get some text in between the date and the time? Do I have to use the same variable twice, once for date and one for time with the text in between or is there a better solution?

Comment: Try escaping your "at" : `date('Y-m-d \a\t H:i:s')`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I tried, but that results in `2018-10-22 15:03:18` (a blank space only).

Comment: \\a\\t does work with Twig ;) Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: escaping could be the right solution but so you can't translate it, probably is better you prefer the @Michal G solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
{{ dateTimeVariable |date('Y-m-d') }} at {{ dateTimeVariable |date('H:i:s') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Escaping words and characters in Twig has to be done with a double backslah `\\`, therefore what works is:

```
{{ dateTimeVariable |date('Y-m-d \\a\\t H:i:s') }}
```

For more information see the [Twig Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html).